# How to check if a cell has a bottom border with Phpexcel

Tags: php, if-statement, phpexcel

How to check if a cell has a bottom border using PHPexcel? I am working on a very funky template the sales force of my company have assembled.

The lines could go on and on inside the "Why?" block so that is why I need to check for that last bottom border to move on in my loop.

Example:
[image: example image for how to check if a cell has a bottom border with Phpexcel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using something like this (didn't really find the bottom border a reliable solution). This will just simply grab the data inside of the following cell ranges (B25:B29):

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheetIndex)->rangeToArray('B25:B29');
```

Answer (score 1):

This will check the entire G column until it is empty

NumCells  = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row +1

If Range("G" & NumCells).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous Then

*Continue with code